# DNN Radeditor - hyperlink manager

Tags: hyperlink, dotnetnuke

Since I updated to version 06.02.00 the hyperlink manager only displays the pages from the portal 0 rather then the new parent portal I am creating. I have searched on Google last few days and couldnt find anything. This is only effecting the new portals and not the existing portals that were created prior to this install.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The Hyperlink manager is developer and supported by DNN folks. You can ask them directly in their forums http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/108/threadid/364908/scope/posts/Default.aspx